# UITableView With Custom Cell (With .xib) Crashing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am facing a strange issue with UITableView custom Cell. I have custom cell class and its .xib and i have registered both xib and class with tableview. But the application get crashed with an error as given,

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0xa75ccb0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tripName.'

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks !!

Comment: This question has been asked and answered tons of times. Did you search yet?

Comment: Non of those answers helped me. Thats why I posted again. Many answers are there and it seems work arounds, not pointing to actual problem. If I am not connecting my label tripName in xib, there is no exception. But I can't set value to trip name.

Answer (score 2):

May be your outlet `tipname` remains in xib.Try to remove it

**Go to Xib -> right Click on yellow square in xib or white square -> there should be `tipname` -> click on cross(remove the outlet not need) -> clean,compile and run the code**

Comment: If I removes the outlet how can i set value dynamically? If I removed, then no exception is happening.

Comment: You should disconnect it and connect it again.What is fileowner of class?Cannot say anything without looking structure of project.But you need to reconnect or transfer the `tipname` in your custom cell class

Comment: Thanks for your support. I have found the issue and posted the answer for this issue.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my time!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found the actual issue. Here I set the Custom Cell Class to File's Owner. I have removed that and set Custom Cell Class to UITableViewCell in the Xib. File's owner set to NSObject.